# What's the best implementation for transparent background with progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a `Button` on an `Activity`. If user press this `Button`, start some network operation. I want obscure content and show progress bar at center.

My current implementation here:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
        android:background="@color/alphaDisabled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm use container because want to block clicking on any `Button` on the screen, while network work not finished.

I try use only progress bar (without container). But in this case progress bar scaled to whole screen.

Is the way with framelayout + progressbar is best way (implemetation + perfomance)?

Comment: User progressDialog. You don't need the FrameLayout for that.

Comment: I can not use ProgressDialog, because own designer want to have obscure + progress.

Comment: In that case your approach is the best way. You can use Frame Layout or Relative Layout or Linear Layout to set the transparency of the background.

Comment: there is many way... But best way depend on your demand.... Why you don't want the progress bar scaled to whole screen?

Comment: @EnamulHaque sir this is the requirement. Now a days many applications are doing this. Even I used the same approach instead of Progress Dialog which darken the screen.Using this custom thing you can change the transparency of your background. :)

Comment: @Enamul Haque, it seems poorly. Also, Google Play for example sometimes show progress bar too and it's located at center without scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current implementation (I always has root view ConstraintLayout):

```
public class ScreenProgress extends FrameLayout {

    public ScreenProgress(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScreenProgress(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScreenProgress(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            return;
        }

        ViewsUtils.setVisible(false, this);

        bindContainer();
        addProgressBar();
    }

    private void bindContainer() {
        setClickable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(ResourcesUtils.getColor(R.color.alphaDisabled));

        ViewParent viewParent = getParent();

        if (!(viewParent instanceof ConstraintLayout)) {
            return;
        }

        ConstraintLayout parent = (ConstraintLayout) viewParent;
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(parent);
        set.connect(getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        set.connect(getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        set.connect(getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
        set.connect(getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
        set.constrainHeight(getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
        set.constrainWidth(getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
        set.applyTo(parent);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setElevation(ResourcesUtils.getDp8());
        }
    }

    private void addProgressBar() {
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(getContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        addView(bar, lp);
    }
}
```

And add to xml:

```
<.ui.view.ScreenProgress
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a 'ProgressBarDialog'

Something like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
//Now you can set some properties of this dialog. Such as, its style, its text etc.

progress.setMessage("Uploading file: ");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Now you can use *progress.show()* and *progress.dismiss()* to show/hide the dialog

Comment: As per the question requirement you can not use STYLE_HORIZONTAL you have to use ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER.

Comment: @YShinkarev Using a ProgressDialog should make the background dim

Answer (score 0):

### Best way I think...

Create a custom ProgressDialog theme in style.xml

```
<style name="MyProgressDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle2</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now create progress dialog with this theme with transparent background and without Dim the hole page...

```
// Initialize a new instance of progress dialog with custom theme 
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);

// Set progress dialog style spinner
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

// Set the progress dialog background TRANSPARENT color 
pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

//Disable the dialog cancel on touch
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setIndeterminate(false);

// Finally, show the progress dialog
pd.show();
```

Enjoy coding :)